# Can't change NSPersistentContainer into NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, cloudkit

I want my exiting project that's using Core Data to enable it use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.

So I set up my project as below documentation "Setting Up Core Data with CloudKit" says.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

But if I change NSPersistentContainer into NSPersistentCloudKitContainer an error occures.

The error message is "Use of undeclared type 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainer'".

Why this happens?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
   // Error occurs here.
   lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "DataModelName")

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container

    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {

                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The requirements are Xcode 11 and the macOS 10.15 / iOS 13 SDK

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understood. So I couldn't build it. Thanks for your help.